# How is it the case that a contract's deployed code is longer than 24.576KB given EIP 170?

Tags: bytecode, deployed-bytecode, eip170, creationcode

The deployed code associated with the contract address 0x05c848E3547Bc3Ccd977B84140FDC917Bfff96a1 is longer than EIP 170 permits (I think?). I know I'm misunderstanding something, but am struggling to find an answer. Can someone explain or point me in the right direction? I'm new to this, obviously. I am aware of the "diamond pattern" (https://dev.to/mudgen/ethereum-s-maximum-contract-size-limit-is-solved-with-the-diamond-standard-2189). Is this how?

Here's a link to the contract on etherescan. https://etherscan.io/address/0x05c848e3547bc3ccd977b84140fdc917bfff96a1#code

It's a verified contract so I know the creation-bytecode is included. Still, calling web3.getCode() on this contract address returns a longer than expected runtime bytecode. Are the values proceeding PUSH opcodes discounted?

Comment: I don't know if I'm correct so I'm just leaving a comment: the creation code on Etherscan shows that it's less than 24KB at 23880 bytes. Perhaps you got the *string* size of the code (which is 47760 bytes) mixed up with the actual bytecode size?

Comment: @bru53001 I think you're right. I'll leave the question open for now, just for others to confirm. I knew it was likely a misunderstanding on my end. Agh! Thank you.